# sbrk - Valgrind doesn't report the memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory, valgrind

I wrote this little version of `malloc` (no `free`):

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unistd.h>

#define word_size sizeof(intptr_t)
#define align(n) ((n + word_size - 1) & ~(word_size - 1))

void* my_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* p = sbrk(0);
    printf("before allocation: %p\n", p);
    if (sbrk(align(size)) == (void*) -1) {
        // failed to allocate memory
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("after allocation: %p\n", sbrk(0));
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int* foo = (int*) my_malloc(1);
    *foo = 100;
    printf("after allocation outside: %p\n", sbrk(0));
}
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
before allocation: 0x1796000
after allocation: 0x1796008
after allocation outside: 0x1796008
```

As you can see, the memory allocated by `my_malloc` has not been freed.
Yet when I run it through `valgrind` with this:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./main
```

I get this:

```
==1592== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1592== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1592== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1592== Command: ./main
==1592== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1592==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1592==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 73,728 bytes allocated
==1592== 
==1592== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1592== 
==1592== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1592== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see, `valgrind` didn't find *any* memory leaks! Am I using `valgrind` incorrectly, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is not very accurate.

Short answer for the OP: Valgrind won't detect a leak in custom memory pools unless you tell it more about your allocator.

Long answer.

When you run `valgrind` there are two executables that will run. Firstly `valgrind` itself. This is a small application that will read a few command line arguments, set a few environment variables then look at the guest application to determine its bitness and then `execve` the appropriate tool, for instance `memcheck-x86-freebsd`.

The tool does not link with **anything**. Not libc, not even the libc startup code. The entry point is in assembler that creates a new stack and starts `valgrind_main`. Since the tool links with nothing, it has to implement for itself all of the C runtime functions that it needs or wants to use. This includes some functions that compilers may implicitly generate. For instance, code that does struct assignment may result in the compiler generating a call to `memcpy()`. This is what the quoted text is referring to. These functions are also provided by the tool rather than libc. This is not related to the redirection mechanism.

So, redirection. `valgrind` will have set `LD_PRELOAD` (or a platform specific version such as `LD_32_PRELOAD`). This will point to a 'core' component (such as `vgpreload_core-x86-freebsd.so` and a tool component such as `vgpreload_memcheck-x86-freebsd.so`. The tool does the job of the link loader, and will `mmap` these files into memory. During this process it will read the `Elf` information and note any "special" functions. These functions use an elaborate name mangling system, and the tool will recognize that, for instance, `_vgr10010ZU_libcZdsoZa_malloc` is a replacement for `malloc` in `libc`. The addresses of these redirection functions are stored and will be used when the guest executes. This mechanism also means that different tools can redirect different functions. For instance, `memcheck` needs to redirect the `malloc` and `new` families of functions whilst `DRD` and `Helgrind` need to redirect `pthread_*` and `sema_*`.

For the other end of the redirection, the tool will also see the target function(s) when it loads libc (and the executable binary itself, which covers
the case of static linking).

The redirection does not fully replace the target function, it just acts as a shim allowing the tool to track what the function has requested.

Now to get right back to `sbrk`. Valgrind does know about this, but only as a syscall. It will check that the `size` argument does not come from invalid storage. `memcheck` won't track the memory as it does with `malloc`. If you use `massif` with `--pages-as-heap=yes` then it will profile the `sbrk` usage.

If you want `memcheck` to validate your custom allocation functions then you have to do one of two things.

- Use standard names and the `--soname-synonyms` argument
- [Use the client request mechanism](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools).

UPDATE:
The default [since Release 3.12.0 (20 October 2016)] has changed to look for
replacement functions in the test exe, text updated.

Answer (score -1):

Valgrind checks for memory leaks by linking in its own functions in place of `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `free`.  You can see this when valgrind reports a memory leak:

```
==24877== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==24877==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==24877==    by 0x4EC3AA9: strdup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==24877==    by 0x40058E: main (x1.c:9)
```

You can see here that the libc version of `strdup` is called but the valgrind  replacement for `malloc` is called instead of the libc `malloc`.

You're allocating memory at a lower level using `sbrk`.  Valgrind doesn't intercept that function, so it won't detect a leak.  In fact, according to the [valgrind documentation](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-tech-docs.html), it lists `sbrk` as a dependency.  From section 1.1.4:

> To find out which glibc symbols are used by Valgrind, reinstate the
>   link flags `-nostdlib -Wl,-no-undefined`. This causes linking to fail,
>   but will tell you what you depend on. I have mostly, but not entirely,
>   got rid of the glibc dependencies; what remains is, IMO, fairly
>   harmless. AFAIK the current dependencies are: `memset`, `memcmp`, `stat`,
>   `system`, `sbrk`, `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: Hm Are you sure? Will valgrind work with statically linked executables?

Comment: I though Valgrind is a "sandbox" intersecting lower level instructions.

Comment: Are you sure about this? A link maybe?

Comment: OK, here it is - please check out section 4.5 here: https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html - you can define a "synonym" for `malloc`. Still not clear how it can work with statically linked executable though